# Where can I find a specific documentation for a Mongoid class?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I am new to Mongoid and I want to learn more about it. Today I came across `Mongoid::Timestamps` in [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-documents/#timestamping) .

It looks interesting to me so I wanted to know more about it, but could not find any more documentation on `Mongoid::Timestamps`. I've currently tried searching [here](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/?_ga=1.78327124.1767721205.1472461320), in Class List, Method List and File List, but didn't find anything.

Seems like Mongoid has a very limited documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**read its RubyDoc**](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Timestamps) to find more about `Mongoid::Timestamps`. It's nothing special, but **in a nutshell:**

> Including `Mongoid::Timestamps` in your Ruby model classes would tell MongoDB to save timestamps of when a document was created or updated. This creates two new attributes in your model:
>
> - created_at
> - updated_at

You use it like this:

```rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  # Other stuff...
end
```

Comment: Oh thanks for the link! It is weird that in mongo site they don't mention anything about RubyDoc. RubyDoc is way more clear. One more thing though, in this RubyDoc which version for Mongoid is talking about? I am using Mongoid 6.0 right now and I am worried if RubyDoc is up-to-date.

Comment: Mongoid was originally a separate project, which got later merged into the MongoDB website. [See the original website here](https://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/index.html).